# Creating a series of Quarters

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, datetime

Let say I have a date

```
import datetime as datetime

mydate = datetime.date(2020, 1, 10)
```

Now starting from `mydate`, I want to create an array of `10` quarters e.g. `2020-Q1, 2020-Q2, ... [total 10 values]`

Is there any direct way to achieve this?

In `R`, this is pretty straightforward, as I can use `seq()` function to generate the same.

Any pointer will be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it doesnt give you the exact format ... but probably close enough

```
pandas.date_range("2020-01-01",freq="Q",periods=10).to_period('Q')
```

Comment: Why using pandas when you can do it in one line raw ??

Answer (score 0):

Be carefaul : datetime.date gives you a date, not a datetime !

You could try something like :

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

mydate = datetime(2020, 1, 10)

quarters = []
for i in range(1, 10):
   quarters.append(mydate + timedelta(minutes=15) * i)
```

Or in one line statement :

```py
quarters = [ mydate + timedelta(minutes=15) * i for i in range(1, 10) ]
```

pretty straightforward too... ;-)

Comment: this is quarter hours not fiscal quarters